# Extract text from a list to create dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of product description like this:

```
l = ['Thương hiệu Kingston',
 'Kích thước Đang cập nhật',
 'Model 3.0 DT100G3 - 64GB',
 'Xuất xứ Đài Loan',
 'SKU 6100242115914',
 'MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM',
 'Dung lượng 64GB',
 'Vỏ kim loại chắc chắn và bền bỉ',
 'USB 3.0 tốc độ cao',
 'Nhỏ gọn dễ dàng mang theo bên mình',
 'Thiết kế không nắp kiểu dáng thời trangTương thích với hầu hết các hệ điều hành',
 'Thiết kế mạnh mẽ',
 'USB Kingston DT100G3 - 64GB - USB 3.0 mang trên mình lớp vỏ ngoài mạnh mẽ, vuông vắn với nền tảng nhựa nhám đen. Bốn cạnh được bo vát tròn hạn chế đâm chọt khi mang theo trong túi quần, túi áo. Phần đầu còn lại có rãnh xỏ dây cho phép bạn ghép đôi chiếc USB này đến những vật bất ly thân như chìa khóa chẳng hạn.',
 'Tốc độ nhanh chóng với chuẩn 3.0',
 'Sử dụng công nghệ USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu giữa máy tính và các thiết bị một cách nhanh chóng và an toàn nhất. Dùng lượng lưu trữ 64GB giúp bạn thoải mái trong việc lưu trữ và chia sẻ văn bản, âm nhạc, videos.',
 'Nắp đậy an toàn, thời trang',
 'Khác với kiểu USB đậy nắp thường thấy, USB Kingston 64GB DT100G3 có màn biến hình khá ấn tượng kiểu “ lên đạn súng lục” bằng cách trượt phần vỏ để lộ ra đầu giao tiếp 3.0 ẩn bên trong. Kiểu thiết kế này rất hữu ích khi không còn sợ thất lạc nắp đậy, giữ cho đầu giao tiếp được bảo bọc an toàn.',
 'Tính năng Plug and Play',
 'Bên cạnh đó, usb với tính năng Plug and Play, bạn chỉ cần cắm vào máy tính là có thể sử dụng không cần phải cài đặt bất kỳ phần mềm nào khác.',
 'Khả năng tương thích cao',
 'Kingston DT100G3 được trang bị cổng kết nối USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu với tốc độ nhanh gấp nhiều lần so với cổng 2.0. Đồng thời, cổng USB 3.0 cũng tương thích ngược với USB 2.0.  Bạn có thể kết nối dễ dàng với thiết bị thông qua cổng USB 3.0 và sử dụng ngay mà không cần cài đặt bất kì phần mềm nào.',
 '']
```

Questions: How can I extract a part of text in this list? Specifically, I want to extract and make a dictionary with `key = "MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM"` and all the remaining lines after `"MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM"` will be the value.

```
dic = {'MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM': "Dung lượng 64GB, Vỏ kim loại chắc chắn và bền bỉ',
 USB 3.0 tốc độ cao, Nhỏ gọn dễ dàng mang theo bên mình, Thiết kế không nắp kiểu dáng thời trang Tương thích với hầu hết các hệ điều hành, Thiết kế mạnh mẽ, USB Kingston DT100G3 - 64GB - USB 3.0 mang trên mình lớp vỏ ngoài mạnh mẽ, vuông vắn với nền tảng nhựa nhám đen. Bốn cạnh được bo vát tròn hạn chế đâm chọt khi mang theo trong túi quần, túi áo. Phần đầu còn lại có rãnh xỏ dây cho phép bạn ghép đôi chiếc USB này đến những vật bất ly thân như chìa khóa chẳng hạn., Tốc độ nhanh chóng với chuẩn 3.0, Sử dụng công nghệ USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu giữa máy tính và các thiết bị một cách nhanh chóng và an toàn nhất. Dùng lượng lưu trữ 64GB giúp bạn thoải mái trong việc lưu trữ và chia sẻ văn bản, âm nhạc, videos., Nắp đậy an toàn, thời trang, Khác với kiểu USB đậy nắp thường thấy, USB Kingston 64GB DT100G3 có màn biến hình khá ấn tượng kiểu “ lên đạn súng lục” bằng cách trượt phần vỏ để lộ ra đầu giao tiếp 3.0 ẩn bên trong. Kiểu thiết kế này rất hữu ích khi không còn sợ thất lạc nắp đậy, giữ cho đầu giao tiếp được bảo bọc an toàn., Tính năng Plug and Play, Bên cạnh đó, usb với tính năng Plug and Play, bạn chỉ cần cắm vào máy tính là có thể sử dụng không cần phải cài đặt bất kỳ phần mềm nào khác., Khả năng tương thích cao, Kingston DT100G3 được trang bị cổng kết nối USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu với tốc độ nhanh gấp nhiều lần so với cổng 2.0. Đồng thời, cổng USB 3.0 cũng tương thích ngược với USB 2.0.  Bạn có thể kết nối dễ dàng với thiết bị thông qua cổng USB 3.0 và sử dụng ngay mà không cần cài đặt bất kì phần mềm nào."}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which creates a dictionary from the first occurrence of `key`. The result dictionary is empty if `key` does not exist in `l`.

```
key = "MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM"
result = {}
for i, line in enumerate(l):
    if line == key:
        result[key] = ", ".join(l[i:])
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string that you are making the key is known and will be present in full within the list as a single string, you can get the index of the key and sublist the rest of the list. Afterwards, convert the sublist into a substring using string join, then place the key and value into a dictionary.

```
l = ['Thương hiệu Kingston',
 'Kích thước Đang cập nhật',
 'Model 3.0 DT100G3 - 64GB',
 'Xuất xứ Đài Loan',
 'SKU 6100242115914',
 'MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM',
 'Dung lượng 64GB',
 'Vỏ kim loại chắc chắn và bền bỉ',
 'USB 3.0 tốc độ cao',
 'Nhỏ gọn dễ dàng mang theo bên mình',
 'Thiết kế không nắp kiểu dáng thời trangTương thích với hầu hết các hệ điều hành',
 'Thiết kế mạnh mẽ',
 'USB Kingston DT100G3 - 64GB - USB 3.0 mang trên mình lớp vỏ ngoài mạnh mẽ, vuông vắn với nền tảng nhựa nhám đen. Bốn cạnh được bo vát tròn hạn chế đâm chọt khi mang theo trong túi quần, túi áo. Phần đầu còn lại có rãnh xỏ dây cho phép bạn ghép đôi chiếc USB này đến những vật bất ly thân như chìa khóa chẳng hạn.',
 'Tốc độ nhanh chóng với chuẩn 3.0',
 'Sử dụng công nghệ USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu giữa máy tính và các thiết bị một cách nhanh chóng và an toàn nhất. Dùng lượng lưu trữ 64GB giúp bạn thoải mái trong việc lưu trữ và chia sẻ văn bản, âm nhạc, videos.',
 'Nắp đậy an toàn, thời trang',
 'Khác với kiểu USB đậy nắp thường thấy, USB Kingston 64GB DT100G3 có màn biến hình khá ấn tượng kiểu “ lên đạn súng lục” bằng cách trượt phần vỏ để lộ ra đầu giao tiếp 3.0 ẩn bên trong. Kiểu thiết kế này rất hữu ích khi không còn sợ thất lạc nắp đậy, giữ cho đầu giao tiếp được bảo bọc an toàn.',
 'Tính năng Plug and Play',
 'Bên cạnh đó, usb với tính năng Plug and Play, bạn chỉ cần cắm vào máy tính là có thể sử dụng không cần phải cài đặt bất kỳ phần mềm nào khác.',
 'Khả năng tương thích cao',
 'Kingston DT100G3 được trang bị cổng kết nối USB 3.0 giúp truyền tải dữ liệu với tốc độ nhanh gấp nhiều lần so với cổng 2.0. Đồng thời, cổng USB 3.0 cũng tương thích ngược với USB 2.0.  Bạn có thể kết nối dễ dàng với thiết bị thông qua cổng USB 3.0 và sử dụng ngay mà không cần cài đặt bất kì phần mềm nào.',
 '']

index = l.index("MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM")
remaining = l[index+1:]
value = ",".join(remaining)

dict = {"MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM" : value}
print(dict)
```

In this case we use `",".join(remaining)` so that the "," will appear between the values that are in the sublist when converted to a string. Keep in mind that the last blank string will cause the value in the dictionary to end with a "," because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the `.index` method on the list to find the location of the value you're interested in, and then slice the list after that value:

```
split_from = "MÔ TẢ SẢN PHẨM"
# grab the index of the string we want to split on
at = l.index(split_from)
# grab anything after it, if the item is not empty
after_split = [c for c in l[at+1:] if c != '']
# join with commas
d = {split_from: ", ".join(after_split)}
print(d)
```